# Programmatic (using HTML, javascript, ?) create link to open excel/doc/pps files in client application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Lately, I'm facing a problem with SP 2013. I Created my own GUI in .aspx file but without using any Web Art. I created view list of files using REST API, and now I want to open files but not in browser online app but in a client application.
I have enabled "auto open I client application" option and this works but only when I open a file directly from Directory Library. 
The only option (i think) in my case does this programmatically using HTML or jQuery.
Is this even possible?

I found something like this:

```
<a href="[SiteURL]/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=[FileURL]&action=default">
```

But this opens the document in Online App, not a client.

I also tried this:

```
<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'0','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','')" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','SharePoint.OpenDoc‌uments.3','0','Share‌Point.OpenDocuments'‌,'','','','115','0',‌'0','0x7ffffffffffff‌fff')" href="[FileURL]" DragId="93">File</a>
```

but in IE ask me if I want to save or open and in Chrome getting a popup with the question where I prefer to save.